# Show first 10 entries by userid

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, date

I have a database with entries with columns ids, users and dates. I want to show only the first 10 entries starting the earliest date per user

There could be 1000's of entries for each user, but I only want to show their first 10 entries on the database

Do you know how I can go about that?

Thanks

Comment: ```order by date fetch first 10 rows only;``` https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/fetch-first-rows-just-got-faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY USERS
                ORDER BY DATES
            ) AS RN
        FROM YOUR_TABLE T
    )
WHERE RN <= 10
```

Cheers!!